# Where should the composer.json and composer.lock files should be?

Tags: php, composer-php

I've never used Composer before, but installed it so I could set twig up the recommended way.

I now have composer.json and composer.lock files in two separate directories.  How do I determine where they SHOULD be?  I assume they certainly shouldn't be in my public html root, as one of them has managed to be?

Comment: The `composer` commands should be executed from the top of your application stack. If you have `projectb` in `/home/user/projectb/` and you have projecta in `/home/user/projecta/`, then you should execute your commands in `project`a` and `projectb` directories respectively, outside of `public_html` which would be more like `/home/user/projecta/public_html`..etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The composer.json file should be created at the topmost directory of your project, i.e. the top directory that is in version control. Subdirectories of this directory likely are for example the "public" or "htdocs" or "www" directory which is the document root for the web server.

By using Composer, this directory will also get a "vendor" directory where the packages are being placed, as well as the `composer.lock` file which records the exact versions being installed.

Do commit both `composer.json` and `composer.lock`. Don't commit the `vendor` folder, put it onto the ignore list.